# Series having strict inequality implies limits having strict equality?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, infinity

I was wondering if I have two convergent series, say, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} s_n = s$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} t_n$ = t, and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the terms satisfy:

$s_n > t_n$.

Is it then necessary that we have:

$s > t$?

My intuition wants to say yes, but then I know funky stuff goes down with sums, products, intersections, unions and the likes when they deal with infinity.

When dealing with a situation like this I would probably inductively show the partial sums have a positive difference, then assume that the limits of the series must have a positive difference too. However this isn't rigorous at all to me and I was wondering if there was an actual proof (if this is a true implication).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $s=t$. Since both sums converge, it follows that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (s_n-t_n)=0$. Since $(s_n-t_n)>0$, $\sum_{n=1}^k(s_n-t_n)$ is monotonically increasing in $k$ which means that $s_n=t_n$ must be true, which is a contradiction. Thus $s=t$ iff $s_n=t_n$.

Comment: That's the most you can say about something like this: the series have an equal limit iff their partial sums are equal?
And the rest is up in the air?

Comment: @anakhronizein: could you clarify your comment? If $s_n>t_n$, then $s>t$. That's the conclusion you're seeking right?

Comment: I retract my comment, I wasn't thinking clearly when I read your answer. It is sufficient. Thank you.